# Why firebase must verify that phone number sign-in requests are coming from my app?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

So am working with Firebase phone authenticating and while reading this doc page [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification) there is a section I didn't understand

> To use phone number authentication, Firebase must be able to verify that phone number sign-in requests are coming from your app. There are two ways Firebase Authentication accomplishes this:

I wonder why? and is there are any why to do this without make the user do a reCAPTCHA?

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind captcha is I think is to verify your device. So if you enable SafetyNet it will not promote you to captcha Screen.

Comment: verify what from my device ? the idea behind using this ( to my understanding ) is to verify the phone number not the device itself !

Comment: @WaelFadlÃllåh using phone number has some security concerns you can read that here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#security-concerns and reCaptcha ensure security and allow only verified domains. More details here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#set-up-the-recaptcha-verifier